# Multiple Delete MSSQL delete queries in Java Program

Tags: java, sql, jdbc

I am writing a program where I am changing roles. 
The Change Role process involves deleting from two tables(to clear the current role/group), inserting into two tables(to set the role/group).

I have `allowMultipleQueries = true` in my connection string, but it looks like only the first query is running.

The database is an MSSQL db.

Is there a way to run both queries? Can I delete from both tables?

The code I have is below:

```
JButton changeRoleBtn = new JButton("Change Role");
    changeRoleBtn.setBounds(50, 375, 150, 30);
    changeRoleBtn.setToolTipText("Changes the role of the User");
    changeRoleBtn.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
    {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
        {
            if (requesterRole.isSelected())
            {
                StringBuffer getRolesQuery3 = new StringBuffer("delete from hib.personrole where personid = '");
                getRolesQuery3.append(userID).append("'");
                StringBuffer getRolesQuery4 = new StringBuffer("delete from hib.persongroup where personid = '");
                getRolesQuery4.append(userID).append("'");
                try 
                {
                    ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(getRolesQuery3.toString());
                    ResultSet rs1 = stmt.executeQuery(getRolesQuery4.toString());

                    boolean empty = true;
                    if(empty)
                    {
                        userRoleLbl.setText("The User is a Requester");
                        System.out.println(rs);
                        System.out.println(rs1);
                    }
                }
                catch(Exception e2)
                {
                    System.out.println(e2);
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

I have changed it to have the prepared statement I get the following error though when I run it. `java.sql.SQLException: Invalid parameter index 2.`

```
    changeRoleBtn.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
    {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
        {
            if (requesterRole.isSelected())
            {
                try
                {
                    PreparedStatement ps1, ps2;
                    ps1 = con.prepareStatement("delete from hib.personrole where personid = ?");
                    ps2 = con.prepareStatement("delete from hib.persongroup where personid = ?");

                    ps1.setInt(1, userID);
                    ps2.setInt(2, userID);

                    ps1.executeQuery();
                    ps2.executeQuery();

                    con.commit();

                    userRoleLbl.setText("The user is a requester");

                }
                catch(Exception e3)
                {
                    e3.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: SQL Injection ahead! Better use prepared statements: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html

Comment: you mean like `delete from hib.personrole where personid in ( [pid1], [pid2] )`?

Comment: Javadocs are your friend. `By default, only one ResultSet object per Statement object can be open at the same time. Therefore, if the reading of one ResultSet object is interleaved with the reading of another, each must have been generated by different Statement objects. All execution methods in the Statement interface implicitly close a statment's current ResultSet object if an open one exists.` http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html

Comment: @Lucas No, I mean `delete from hib.personrole where personId = ?` (and then assign the parameter value). Read the link I gave

Comment: @Barranka, my comment was to the OP.  Your suggestion is correct without doubt, i was just asking for clarification on the original question.

Comment: `allowMultiQueries` vs `allowMultipleQueries`. I believe the first is right.

Comment: Good practice is to use executeBatch() [Batch update](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/jdbc/batchupdate.html) for your requirement. Juned Ahsan given that answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to execute each `delete` instruction independently, but there's no restriction to do it.

As I said in my comment, your code is vulnerable to SQL injection, so I suggest you use prepared statements:

```
 // ...
 PreparedStatement ps1, ps2;
 ps1 = con.prepareStatement("delete from hib.personrole where personid = ?");
 ps2 = con.prepareStatement("delete from hib.persongroup where personid = ?");

 ps1.setString(1, userID);
 ps2.setString(1, userID);

 ps1.execute();
 ps2.execute();
 // ...
```

Further reference:

- http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html
- http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html

Hope this helps

Comment: Thank you, it looks like this will work. The problem I am running into though is that the query does not seem to be running.

Comment: @DarthOpto Be sure you are commiting the instructions: `con.commit()`

Comment: @DarthOpto And check if there's an exception popping somewhere (be sure to print the stack trace of all possible exceptions)

Comment: I am getting the following exception: `java.sql.SQLException: Invalid parameter index 2.`

Comment: @DarthOpto Sorry, I had an error (I've corrected it in the post). In `ps2` the correct index is `1`.

Answer (score 6):

I  believe it will be more appropriate to use the batch here.When you send several SQL statements to the database at once, you reduce the amount of communication overhead, thereby improving performance.

JDBC drivers are not required to support this feature. You should use the DatabaseMetaData.supportsBatchUpdates() method to determine if the target database supports batch update processing. The method returns true if your JDBC driver supports this feature.

- The **addBatch**() method of Statement, PreparedStatement, and
  CallableStatement is used to add individual statements to the batch.
  The executeBatch() is used to start the execution of all the
  statements grouped together.
- The **executeBatch**() returns an array of integers, and each element of
  the array represents the update count for the respective update
  statement.
- Just as you can add statements to a batch for processing, you can
  remove them with the **clearBatch**() method. This method removes all the
  statements you added with the addBatch() method. However, you cannot
  selectively choose which statement to remove.

Sample code

```
con.setAutoCommit(false);
stmt.addBatch(getRolesQuery3);  
stmt.addBatch(getRolesQuery4);
ResultSet rs = stmt.executeBatch();
```